# how to get dataframe values in variables

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a dataframe using spark SQL in Java.

```
Dataset<Row> dateDF = spark.sql("select dates from dim_date where dates between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-04'");
```

When I use the `show()` method it returns each date in new line. I understand that it is basically one column.

I want those values in a String variable with single quotes like this:

```
'2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-03,'2017-01-04'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select your column, map to a String with `as` and collect to a list. I think converting a list of String to a single String should not be a problem afterwards:

```
dateDF.select("dates").as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList() //... and so on
```

On Java 8, you can merge values into one String using:

```
dateDF.select("dates").as(Encoders.STRING()).collectAsList().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Thanks @T. Gaweda. It works for me. I am new to spark and was stuck there.

Comment: @Vish No problem, I've just added the last paragraph and code snippet ;) Main idea is from moe.